# How can I build a command line interface which has operators with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse, operation

How can I build the following with argparse:

Synopsis: python3 program.py [operation] [options] target

Operations: install, uninstall, update or remove (you choose one).

I want the operations to have their own set of options. I'm not looking for specific code, just some general guidance.

Comment: Use [`ArgumentParser.add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want [`subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). The `dest='subparser_name'` bit allows you to tell which subparser has been called.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name')
install_parser = subparsers.add_parser('install')
install_parser.add_argument('target')
subparsers.add_parser('uninstall')

print(parser.parse_args(['uninstall']))
print(parser.parse_args(['install', 'target=foo']))
print(parser.parse_args(['uninstall', 'install', 'target=foo']))
```

Output:

```
Namespace(subparser_name='uninstall')
Namespace(subparser_name='install', target='target=foo')
usage: test.py [-h] {install,uninstall} ...
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: install target=foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I am doing for similar requirements, However this might be a very basic method and beginner level:
Example (getopt):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, getopt
def main(argv):
   arg=''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"i:u:r:",["install=","update=","remove="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print('test.py -i <myinput>')
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt in ("-i", "--install"):
         #Your operation
         print('installing something based on my input',arg)
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-u", "--update"):
         #Your operation
         print('updating something based on my input',arg)
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-r", "--remove"):
         #Your operation
         print('removing something based on my input',arg)
         sys.exit()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Reference: [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

Usage:

```
python test.py -i myinput
```

Output:

```
installing something based on my input myinput
```